# Google contacts not displaying birthday in URL option

Tags: google-contacts

So for some reason, the past few days (since I started looking to add a birthday) the birthday option has been blurred out.

see attached picture[image: birthday option not available]

Comment: Are you missing first name and/or last name? Contacts might think this is an entity (like a business) rather than a person.

Comment: The contact has a first and last name.

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be normal behavior, since the default value for that date label *is* "Birthday". Since, if you want to add a birthday you don't need to touch the label, they're making it non-selectable.

I don't know if that's really good UX, but there you have it.

Comment: Yet I can choose Anniversary, save, close out, go back, and I still can't choose Birthday.